# Split an array to another array

Tags: angularjs

I have a month Array `monthArr`with data like `Jan, Feb, Mar` at its `0` index.

```
monthArr = [{Jan, Feb, Mar}]
```

I want to `split` this array in another array with `,` as split point, so far I have got to this:

```
angular.forEach($scope.monthArr, function(value, key){
       $scope.monthArrSplit[key] = String($scope.monthArr).split(",")[value]
})
```

Comment: I don't understand the question. Could you post an example of the desired output?

Comment: `[{Jan, Feb, Mar}]` is not correct... Do you mean `['Jan, Feb, Mar']`?

Comment: Or `[{Jan:1, Feb:2, Mar:3}]` ?

Comment: It is like [{0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar"}]

Comment: could you please be more clear and precise on your requirement here !.

Answer (score 0):

Check out This

```js
var jimApp = angular.module("mainApp",  []);

jimApp.controller('mainCtrl', function($scope){
    var monthArr =  [{0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar"}];
    //angular.forEach 
    
    $scope.monthArrSplit = [];
    angular.forEach(monthArr[0], function(value, key){
       $scope.monthArrSplit.push(value);
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="mainApp" ng-controller="mainCtrl">
  {{monthArrSplit}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have array of objects then you need two nested loops. Like this:

```
var monthsList = [{0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar"}];
for(var monthObj of monthsList){
    for(var prop in monthObj) {
        console.log(monthObj[prop])
    }
}
```

Or in agular way like this:

```
var monthsList = [{0: "Jan", 1: "Feb", 2: "Mar"}];
angular.forEach(monthsList, function(value){
   angular.forEach(value, function(value, key){
       $scope.monthArrSplit.push(value);
    })
})
```

Answer (score 0):

first thing you can't split the array using split(). split() only split the string value

you should be use slice().

```
var monthArr = [{Jan, Feb, Mar}];

angular.forEach($scope.monthArr, function(value, key){
  var spliceVar = monthArr[0].slice(","); 
  console.log(spliceVar.length);
})

O/P :- 3
```